# How to generate value of a field using trigger?

Tags: mysql, triggers, phpmyadmin

I need to write a trigger in MySQL to make sure whenever a new row is inserted into a table, the value of one of its fields will be populated by a specific value that is generated from combination of values of other fields.

As you can see at first I need to replace all spaces in the name field with -, then concat it with - and value of phone field and at the end put the result into nickname field.

**Trigger**

```
The following query has failed: "CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` 
TRIGGER `generatenickname` BEFORE INSERT ON `Users` 
FOR EACH ROW 
DECLARE temp = REPLACE(NEW.name, " ", "-"); 
SET NEW.nickname = concat(temp + '-' + NEW.phone);"
MySQL said: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the 
manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right 
syntax to use near 'DECLARE temp = REPLACE(NEW.name, " ", "-"); SET 
NEW.nickname = concat(t' at line 1
```

If I surround it with BEGIN and END; and remove "FOR EACH ROW" it does not show error but put 0 in nickname field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this it's solve your problem.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER  `generatenickname` BEFORE INSERT ON `Users` 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
SET NEW.NAME = CONCAT(REPLACE(NEW.name, " ", "-") , '-' , NEW.phone);
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: thanks, then why declaring a new variable did not work?

Answer (score 0):

Your trigger contains multiple statements, and as such you need to enclose them in a BEGIN...END block.

Refer to the documentation:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-trigger.html
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/trigger-syntax.html

Comment: I put BEGIN before "For EACH ROW" and END; at the end of the trigger but still returns same error.